# laravel only allow acces to own ressources

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I would like to make sure that users can only access their own data.
I could do it with a route that just return the authenticated user:

```
Route::get('/user', function() { return auth()->user(); });
```

However I was told that this is not RESTful since it would return different things depending on whoever is logged in. Instead it should be:

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@index');
```

and then I would need to check in the UserController that the passed id is actually the authenticated users id. It seems like an easy way to mess up and expose data accidentally.

What method is preferable?

Comment: You're writing a REST api? and which authentication method you're using?

Comment: you can use middleware for that.

Comment: Yes it is a rest api. It may use token or session based authentication

Comment: If the passed id is not the id of the authenticaed user what you should do ??

Comment: `/user` does not have an ID in the route. So If i go to `yoursite.com/user`, it would return the authenticated user data. It could be my credentials or the credentials of the last person who logged in and forgot to log out. If you give each user a unique id, and I go to `/users/myUniqueID,` it will never conflict with another user's data. So it is recommended never to use a shared URL for unique data. Similarly, if I wanted to access my own profile, I would go to `/users/myUniqueID/profile`

Comment: See [Restful API design guidelines](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9)

Answer (score 0):

every time when you geting data related to user you should do this by `Auth::user()->data` thing i would do that